# Can you use 2 metamagic rods to improve a single spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I was just wondering, I have a cleric and he has a Greater Metamagic Rod: Maximize, I was thinking of picking up a Greater Empower Rod as well, would they two rods stack, or can I only use one?

I don't see why I couldn't Maximize and then Empower a spell, since it doesn't take any spell slots from me, and bringing down a Rain of Fire that is maximized and empowered (153 HP, oh yeah, go go super cleric) onto my unsuspecting foes, just rocks my world.

Answer (score 20):

**No**, you can't simultaneously use two metamagic rod on the same spell: see [Pathfinder Reference Document](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/rods.html#metamagic-rods).

> **Metamagic Rods**
>   Metamagic rods hold the essence of a metamagic feat, allowing the user to apply metamagic effects to spells (but not spell-like abilities) as they are cast. This does not change the spell slot of the altered spell. All the rods described here are use-activated (but casting spells in a threatened area still draws an attack of opportunity). *A caster may only use one metamagic rod on any given spell*, but it is permissible to combine a rod with metamagic feats possessed by the rod's wielder. In this case, only the feats possessed by the wielder adjust the spell slot of the spell being cast.
>   [...]

Emphasis mine.